# Minimum and maximum timestamps per hour bucket

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-datetime

I've a text file with timestamps.

Example:

```
16-07-2015 18:08:20
16-07-2015 18:08:22
16-07-2015 18:08:30
16-07-2015 18:08:40
17-07-2015 10:04:01
17-07-2015 10:14:31
17-07-2015 10:14:59
17-07-2015 12:24:11
....
```

Now I need the min and max value per hour, as shown in the example below.

Example:

```
16-07-2015 18:08:20 - 16-07-2015 18:08:40
17-07-2015 10:04:01 - 17-07-2015 10:14:59
17-07-2015 12:24:11 - ....
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Stack Overflow works best when helping you fix your own code. Are the timestamps always *sorted* in the file?

Comment: Also, did you want your output as a string, or are you looking for results as `datetime` objects and your formatted output is just an example?

Comment: Converted string to datetime object, but after that I'm stuck. They're sorted in the file. Need the formatted output but that should not be a problem. Finding the min and max per hour is my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an iterable of `datetime` objects, you can group them by day and hour, then find the first and last of these with [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def min_max_per_hour(iterable):
    for dayhour, grouped in groupby(iterable, lambda dt: (dt.date(), dt.hour)):
        minimum = next(grouped)  # first object is the minimum for this hour
        maximum = minimum  # starting value
        for dt in grouped:
            maximum = dt   # last assignment is the maximum within this hour
        yield (minimum, maximum)
```

This relies on the iterable containing the `datetime` objects in *sorted order*.

To produce the input iterable, parse the textfile in a generator expression or another generator; there is no need to keep everything in memory all at once:

```
from datetime import datetime

with open(input_filename) as inf:
    # generator expression
    datetimes = (datetime.strptime(line.strip(), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') for line in inf)
    for mindt, maxdt in min_max_per_hour(datetimes):
        print mindt, maxdt
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def min_max_per_hour(iterable):
...     for dayhour, grouped in groupby(iterable, lambda dt: (dt.date(), dt.hour)):
...         minimum = next(grouped)  # first object is the minimum for this hour
...         maximum = minimum  # starting value
...         for dt in grouped:
...             maximum = dt   # last assignment is the maximum within this hour
...         yield (minimum, maximum)
...
>>> textfile = '''\
... 16-07-2015 18:08:20
... 16-07-2015 18:08:22
... 16-07-2015 18:08:30
... 16-07-2015 18:08:40
... 17-07-2015 10:04:01
... 17-07-2015 10:14:31
... 17-07-2015 10:14:59
... 17-07-2015 12:24:11
... '''.splitlines()
>>> datetimes = (datetime.strptime(line.strip(), '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S') for line in textfile)
>>> for mindt, maxdt in min_max_per_hour(datetimes):
...     print mindt, maxdt
...
2015-07-16 18:08:20 2015-07-16 18:08:40
2015-07-17 10:04:01 2015-07-17 10:14:59
2015-07-17 12:24:11 2015-07-17 12:24:11
```

Comment: It would be better to group by date and hour (`lambda dt: (dt.date(), dt.hour)`) in case the input contains consequent timestamps which have the same hour, but different dates.

Comment: @AudriusKažukauskas: good point. Updated to include the date in the grouping.